# Creating a stopwatch from scratch in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timer, stopwatch

By creating variables for milliseconds, seconds, and minutes, I wanted to make a little stopwatch project.  The `onClick` for the button I have is for `theTimer()`:

```
var milli = 0;
    var seconds = 0;
    var minutes = 0;
    var onOff = 0;

    var txtMilli = document.getElementById("txtMilli");
    var txtSeconds = document.getElementById("txtSeconds");
    var txtMinutes = document.getElementById("txtMinutes");

    function theTimer()
    {
        if (onOff == 0) {
            onOff = 1;
            timer = setInterval("startCounting()",1);
        }
        if (onOff == 1) {
            onOff == 0;
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }

    function startCounting()
    {
        if (milli >999) 
        { 
          milli = 0; if (seconds <60) {seconds +=1} 
        }
        else 
        {
          milli +=1;
        }
        if (seconds >59) 
        {
          seconds = 0; minutes += 1;
        }
        if (milli > 10) 
        {
          txtMilli.innerHTML = "0" + milli;
        }
        if (milli < 10) 
        {
          txtMilli.innerHTML = "" + milli;
        }
    }
```

Nothing shows up in the console, the problem is that the `DIV`s never change from 0 when running it.

Comment: What goes wrong? What happens? What errors are reported in the console?

Comment: Also browsers won't let you run an interval timer at 1 millisecond intervals.

Comment: Sorry.  Nothing shows up in the console, the divs I have set up for the variables never change to anything but 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix your code like so:

```
var milli = 0;
var seconds = 0;
var minutes = 0;
var onOff = 0;

var txtMilli = document.getElementById("txtMilli");
var txtSeconds = document.getElementById("txtSeconds");
var txtMinutes = document.getElementById("txtMinutes");

function startCounting(){        
    if (milli >999) { milli = 0; if (seconds <60) {seconds +=1} }
    else {milli +=1;}
    if (seconds >59) {seconds = 0; minutes += 1;}

    if (milli > 10) {txtMilli.innerHTML = "0" + milli;}
    if (milli < 10) {txtMilli.innerHTML = "" + milli;}
}

function theTimer(){
    if (onOff == 0) {
        onOff = 1;
        timer = setInterval(startCounting, 1);
    } else if (onOff == 1) {
        onOff = 0;
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}

myButton.onclick = theTimer;
```

There was a bug inside `theTimer` where you'd set `onOff` to `1`, then immediately check to see if it was `1` and set it back to `0`. I fixed this by using `else if`.

I also changed `onOff == 0` (which is a comparison) to `onOff = 0` (which is an assignment).

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k83tvfhc/

Comment: I already had the variables initialized to 0.  You misunderstood the purpose of the onOff var.   Its basically pauses it if the button is pressed again while its running.

Comment: @KevinYoung Sorry, I read a little too fast! In any case, #2 is the thing that fixed the bug.

Comment: @KevinYoung The way the code currently works, when you called theTimer(), theTimer() would set onOff to 1, and then immediately check to see if it was 1 and set it back to 0 and clear the interval. You don't want to set it back to 0 until they click the button again, right?

Comment: @KevinYoung (I would also suggest using a boolean rather than 0/1 for `onOff`)

Comment: That's  correct, totally slipped my mind to put the else there.  The project still doesn't run.  Let me make it a jsfiddle right now.

Comment: @KevinYoung It ran for me in JSFiddle :) I will send you a working version

Comment: Thanks.  Here's the complete code that I was working with:   https://jsfiddle.net/hgpu4p4k/1/

Comment: @KevinYoung I put a link to a working jsfiddle. Apparently onclick="" events don't work in jsfiddle, but that's okay because you should really be assigning those events with JS anyways. Another problem I found was that you were doing `onOff == 0` which would prevent you from turning off the stopwatch.

Comment: awesome.  Thanks for the help

Comment: It's not that it does not works, but the parser first reads the inline `onclick` attribute referencing to some function that is not (yet) defined. (Remember DOM ready?)

Comment: @thedayturns https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/c5g4ypnz/ :P - PS: FYI if you click on the `JAVASCRIPT(cog icon)` button in the JavaScript window you'll see the available JS options.

Comment: Also you should not let the `timer` variable fall to global scope.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I call that "not working by default" :P You are correct however, `timer` should be `var timer`.

Comment: @thedayturns :) jsFiddle uses non-blocking methods placing JS before the closing body tag (since placing JS in head in not the best practice) and also the use of inline JS is also bad design - might be worth suggesting to OP. Also: https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/kgm1sur4/ should be a somewhat better demo :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Agreed, though if I took the time to fully correct any OP's code, I'd probably never finish a single SO answer ;-)