# How to start and stop counter by single button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to start counter when I click the button first time and stop when I click on second time.

I tried the following code:

```js
var myTimer;

function clock(){
    myTimer = setInterval(myClock,1000);
    var c = 0;
    function myClock(){
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = ++c;    
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>---Counter----</h1>
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="clock();clearInterval(myTimer);">start</button>
```

I want to start the counter after the initial click of button and stop it in the second click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a `flag` to check if `timer` has started with `true` or `false`.

If the `timer` is started change the `innerText` to stop and and use the same button to `start` the `timer` again.

**Live Demo:**

```js
var myTimer;

//Check if started ot not
var started = false

//Timer
var timer = 0;

//Btn text
var btn = document.getElementById("startBtn")

function clock(e) {
  if (!started) {
    myTimer = setInterval(myClock, 1000);
    started = true
    btn.innerText = 'Stop'
  } else {
    started = false
    clearInterval(myTimer);
    btn.innerText = 'Start'
  }
}

function myClock() {
  if (started) {
    ++timer
    document.getElementById('demo').textContent = timer;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>---Counter----</h1>
<p id="demo"></p>
<button id="startBtn" onclick="clock(this)">start</button>
```

Comment: It worked. Is it possible to change it to start as stopwatch.

Comment: @ashil i am not sure what you mean ? Can you please clarify - It is showing start and stop already which acts like stop watch.

Comment: Like instead of starting a counter and loop through number. Loop through time.Like a stop watch

Comment: @ashil Ahh i see what you mean. Yes its possible but that's a totally seperate question to be honest. There will alot things we need to add (Date, time, intervals) etc etc. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709953/creating-a-stopwatch-from-scratch-in-javascript) or this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318822/how-to-create-a-stopwatch-using-javascript)  will guide you regarding stopwatch. Happy coding :)

Comment: I found a solution. Var minutes = Math.floor(timer/60);var seconds = timer - minutes*60; changing timer to minues and seconds variable in the textContent solved my issue .

Comment: @ashil Glad to hear that. Happy coding Ashil. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I add an eventlistener to the button. If clicked I check if the button contains class start. If not (that's the initial) add this class, set textContent to "stop" and start the clock. Otherwise remove this class set textContent on "start" and clearInterval. Note: For clearing the interval you need to store the return of setInterval in a variable with access at clearing, so I declared it at start global.
If you press button after stop again timer will restart at beginning.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var myTimer;

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (btn.classList.contains('start')) {
        btn.classList.remove('start');
        btn.textContent = "start";
        clearInterval(myTimer);
    } else {
        btn.classList.add('start');
        btn.textContent = "stop";
        clock();
    }
});

function clock(){
    function myClock(){
        document.getElementById('demo').textContent = ++c;
    }
    myTimer = setInterval(myClock,1000);
    var c = 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>---Counter----</h1>
<p id="demo"></p>
<button id="btn">start</button>
```

Comment: Just changing the text - you do not have use `innerHTML` as its not recomeneded at all. Use `textContent` or `text()`

Comment: Thanks you are right this is better style. I changed it.